# Custom proof environment: spacing issue with when optional argument given

Tags: environments, amsthm, optional-arguments

Consider the following code, the purpose of which is to have a proof environment in which the "Proof." bit is bold.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][Proof]{\noindent{\bfseries #1.\ }}{\qed\\[2mm]}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
    $A = X$.
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}[Proof]
    $A = X$.
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}[Proof]%
    $A = X$.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

This produces the following spacing inconsistency:
[image]
In particular, when the optional argument is provided, even when given exactly the same value as the default (Proof), an extra space appears after the period. Adding `%` after the argument bracket close fixes this, but why does this happen? And how to write the environment in such a way that this `%` is not necessary?

Comment: You have an unguarded space at the end of one of the lines. Change `\begin{proof}[Proof]` to `\begin{proof}[Proof]%` to see what I mean.

Comment: This will, of course, fix the issue. But why is the % needed only in the case where an optional argument is provided, and not otherwise?

Comment: Added example with `%`.

Comment: without the argument your proof is skipping spaced looking for [  so the space does not appear, but this definition doesn't control spacing or page breaking or QED position, it would be better to use the facilities of amsthm as you are loading it

Comment: Thank you for the explanation David!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why even redefine the `proof` env when the one from `amsthm` works.

In order to make it bold you can just use

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd\proof{\itshape}{\bfseries}{}{\typeout{Patch of proof failed}}
```

The `\\[2mm]` at the end I'd skip, that is not a good idea.

Comment: The reason why is because the journal I am submitting to defined things this way, including with the `\\[2mm]` at the end. Amsthm then rewrites the definition of proof when I load it (journal tells you not to use amsthm... but I cannot live without it) and I am trying to recreate their proof, while also making it work with the optional argument (which theirs doesn't).

Comment: I agree that this is the correct answer in general!

Comment: @Oxonon if the journal asks you to not use amsthm you follow their request, otherwise they'll have to rewrite your article to fit their design or even refuse to publish it. What exactly is it you cannot live without (having been on the receiving end, it is super annoying when users don't follow the guidelines)

Comment: Submission is PDF only, so what they don't know won't hurt them.

Answer (score 2):

You could add `\ignorespaces` to your definition to ignore spaces at the beginning of the environment:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][Proof]{\noindent{\bfseries #1.\ }\ignorespaces}{\qed\\[2mm]}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
    $A = X$.
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}[Proof]
    $A = X$.
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}[Proof]%
    $A = X$.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

But IMHO using `\ignorespaces` is mostly a workaround. So I would recommend to use a solution like @daleif's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/709115/277964) instead.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I need for my purposes, but as you said, the other solution is probably what people will want if they find this question via search, so I will accept the other answer.